# debugging deobfuscated javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, reverse-engineering

I am trying to reverse-engineer a website I don't own, figuring out how some dumb "encryption" works, in order to be able to carry out some operations automatically, by taking the functionality outside the browser.

One of the files is of particular interest, let's call it `javascript.js`. It is linked in the HTML document like this

```
<script src="/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have

- deobfuscated `javascript.js`
- pretty-printed its code

My question is now, considering that I'm using venkman and firefox, how to replace the on-site obfuscated `javascript.js` with my own pretty-printed code, in order to learn how it works.

Any other tool beside venkman should do, as long as I can still step through the deobfuscated code.

Additional question (just in case I may come cross this related situation):

How to do the same if the `javascript.js` would be emdedded inline in the html code like `<script>code</script>`?

---

For those of you wondering about how legal this is, my question is not the first about reverse-engineering on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reverse-engineering

Apparently there's no problem with those questions, why should there be one with mine?

*My objective is to understand the code* AND my question is about the TOOLS, as in "where to point and click" or which tool could help me (if venkman cannot).

Comment: This question's pretty light on detail. *"how do I replace the code"* Where? Are you trying to inject it into the original site or something?

Comment: I guess the addendum clears up some things

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm assuming you don't have write access to the server/files in question...

Comment: Of course I don't, otherwise I wouldn't deobfuscate my own code and/or I wouldn't be asking how to replace the code ... Doh

Comment: @Flavius: *"I guess the addendum clears up some things"* **Marginally**. How 'bout you take five minutes to actually describe, in some detail, what you're actually trying to do. Rather than having people guess. And getting ratty with tobyodavies is uncalled for. He's trying to help you.

Comment: Anyone still unhappy about the wording now?

Comment: So you want to over ride the JS running on another site with your own?  I'm not sure if I should help with that because it probabilistically seems heavily weighted towards unethical usage.

Comment: I'm not trying to override it on the remote side, I'm trying to override it in my debugger, locally. No breaking in is involved, only understanding code - that's my aim.

Comment: How about mirroring the website with httrack and modifying your local files?

Comment: The said website involves some ajax, I cannot do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also always use an intercepting proxy (something like [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/)) which will allow you to replace any part of the response any way you like. So when the browser requests the JS file, you can catch the response in Paros, replace the content with your version, and you're done. I often use Paros for other things where I need that interception or observation point, and it's pretty simple and quite numerous in its possible applications. It's basically just a matter of running it and setting your browser proxy settings to use a proxy at localhost on the port Paros is listening on. You can then tell Paros to actually stop and allow you to edit the request or response just by checking a couple of boxes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed this is the best answer. While I've not tried it yet, I will accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: Btw, you'd deserve more +1 for the simple fact that you've thought outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be very difficult, if not impossible, to do without using browser debugging / extension features like GreaseMonkey or Chrome's Extension API. The reason being that if you don't get involved in the page load sequence, the obfuscated code will already have been run, setting up JavaScript objects, event handlers, etc., etc. You'd have to ensure that your new script replaced those objects and event handlers, which would be complicated and difficult.

With GreaseMonkey or Chrome Extensions or similar on whatever browser you're using, I'd expect it to be possible to detect the page loading script X and replace it with your local script Y. These things run at that level, they get involved in the process.

But despite your goals being aboveboard, **debugging on someone else's site is a *bad idea***. If you introduce a bug through the deobfuscation process, or in the process of trying to understand the code, well that may at least waste time at the other end. I wouldn't be happy with people trying to do it on a site I was running. (That said, a site should be able to handle *anything* a client throws at it, because you can't trust anything coming from the client side.)

Instead of debugging on their site, I'd probably do my best to record (via Firebug or Chrome/Safari's Dev Tools, etc.) a sample ajax interaction, and then set up a dummy page on my own local server that would simply echo that interaction, playback style. Then you can experiment to your heart's content without risking throwing weird stuff at the site in question. I'd consider it unethical for me to play around in that way with someone else's site, whether they should be able to handle it or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at XUL and XPCOM.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**:
Export the web page that uses the code to your drive (I know for sure Opera, Firefox and Chrome supports this - ctrl+s - make sure to save all content). They download all linked content (css, scripts, images), and fix the url's so the downloaded ones are loaded instead. Then replace the javascript file you want to debug and open the downloaded html in a browser, say firefox with firebug, and start debugging. This should work unless the page is heavily ajaxified.

**Way 2**:
I've managed to get this working in **Google Chrome** (*v8.0.552.215* - I need to update BTW) on a page that has no jQuery (for example [w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/)) - try it yourself, just copy paste it in the address bar and wait for the page to disappear :)

```
javascript:(eval("var script=document.createElement('script');script.src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);window.setTimeout(\"$('body').fadeOut(5000);\", 2000)"));
```

The script shows up in the scripts section of the console (*CTRL+SHIFT+J*) and you can set breakpoints. So something like this should work (feel free to modify):

```
javascript:(eval("for (var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName('script'), i=allsuspects.length, oldfile=prompt('Remove script src:'); oldfile && i>=0; i--)   if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute('src')!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf(oldfile)!=-1)      allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]);var script=document.createElement('script');script.src = prompt('Inject script src:');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"));
```

The script expanded and explained:

```
for (var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName('script'), i=allsuspects.length, oldfile=prompt('Remove script src:'); oldfile && i>=0; i--) 
  if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute('src')!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf(oldfile)!=-1)
    allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]); // remove old script
var script=document.createElement('script'); // inject new script
script.src = prompt('Inject script src:');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

The script works only in Chrome (maybe in Safari too?). I've tried Firefox, IE and Opera, but *none* of them worked. I would guess that there might also be an issue if the file is not available online (if you use you use the 'file://').

---

**UPDATE**: also works in Chrome *v8.0.552.224*